# Firebase Realtime Database, what is a read exactly?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am aware for Cloud Firestore a read is a document (whether the documents has 5 or 50 nodes). How does this compare to the RTDB?

If I have a query that has a limit of 25, is this going to be 25 reads, or 25 times x amount of items in each node?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit of a non-sequitur, as realtime database doesn't bill by reads, it bills by [data transferred](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) (and storage, of course).  So, the thing that affects your cost is the size of the items transferred, which is only indirectly based on the number of items due to a limit on the query.  Currently, the costs are about US $1 per GB downloaded assuming you are on the Blaze plan.

To compare this with the costs for Firestore would require knowing a lot more about the shape of your traffic -- how many reads and writes, average size of a read, etc.  Note that Cloud Firestore also indirectly charges for data transferred, but at a much lower rate, as it is only the Google Cloud [Network pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing).

This means that you can generally get quite a large number of Firestore document reads for the cost that RTDB charges for transferring 1 GB..  (e.g. at current prices for egress to most of the internet excluding some asia/pacific destinations, you could get 1 GB + over 1.4M firestore document reads for your $1 of 1 GB RTDB transfer).

The [documentation references](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing) several things you can do to help control costs, including (but not limited to):

- Prefer the native SDKs to the REST API
- Monitoring your data usage and use the profiler tool to measure read operations.
- Use fewer, longer lived connections, as SSL and connection overhead can contribute to your costs (but generally are not the bulk of your cost).
- Ensure your listeners are limited to only the data you care about, and are as low in the database tree as possible, and only download updates, (e.g. `on()` vs `once()`).